# Finding the ID of a widget in a view class

Tags: java, android, xml, view, android-widget

What I have is a canvas that takes up nearly all of the screen, then under that I want a row of buttons and some other widgets. So I did this.

```
XML Code
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/myLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.zone.manager.Tab3
    android:id="@+id/tab3_display"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="620dp" />

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >   

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addZone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Zone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/helpZone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Help" />



        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:paddingTop="9dp"
            android:layout_width="179dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Java Code

```
public class Tab3 extends View implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener {
  public Tab3(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    View parent = (View) getParent();
    addZone = (Button) parent.findViewById(R.id.addZone);
    addZone.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

    @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        . . . draws a bunch of stuff
      }
    @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.addZone:
            String w = "W~20~0~0~0~0~0";
            Log.d("ZoneSize", "Zone set");
            MyApplication.preferences.edit().putString( "ZoneSize", w ).commit();
            MyApplication.preferences.edit().putBoolean("ZoneSizeReady", true).commit();
            break;
        }
      }
```

However my problem with this is that I believe the code is not reconising where the addZone is. Because when I have the `addZone.setOnClickListener` active my program will crash, but when I don't have it active the layout looks like how I want it. What must I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 addZone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addZone);
```

addZone will be **null** because `com.zone.manager.Tab3` does not have any children

So it is obvious that your code will crash

So either you will give **com.zone.manager.Tab** children which require also to change the base class from View to ViewGroup,

or you start with **com.zone.manager.Tab** parent. Something like

```
 View parent = (View) getParent ();
 addZone = (Button) parent.findViewById(R.id.addZone);
```

Comment: What do I need to do in order to fix this than?

Comment: When I do this it still crashes on the start up? ill update the question to show you what I have.

Comment: The second approach does not require to change the base class

Comment: Okay, I did that and it still crashes? What am I doing wrong.

Comment: I don't see more problem. However, Use a debugger and check the values parent and addZone. Both should be not **null**

Comment: it is the `View parent = (View) getParent();` that is causing the crash now. Are you sure that there isnt anything else that must be done with this in order for it to work?

Comment: getParent() returns a ViewParent which is not required to be a View but in general it is. It is likely that you get now a class-cast-exception. There must be something special in your case. Please show the FULL xml (the xml above is only a fragment) and also show the code to create the view.

Comment: Okay, there, now the WHOLE xml is there, I hope you find my problem.

Comment: the xml could NOT be complete. The outer closing LinearLayout is missing. If you just forgot, `View parent = (View) getParent ();`should have worked.

Comment: forgetting the second linear layout was a mistake on my part but I accualy had it there the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

i have some tips which will make you avoid such weird bugs and others:

the code of the custom view relies on an xml layout that uses the custom view .
this is bad coding.

instead, you should use LayoutInflater , use a layout xml file for the custom view for it , and then do the "findViewById" and add the clickListeners to any view inside that you wish.

i think it's also wrong to set the custom view to hold the click listener of the other views without checking which of them was clicked . either add a check , or add a different listener for each of them (which i personally prefer) .